# How to replace all Jmeter extracted variable

Tags: variables, replace, jmeter

[image: Jmeter]

So I used the extractor and usually I just manually replace value with ${afrLoop}
Its fine when there is only a couple of them to replace
but is there a way to replace all of the automatically?
as sometimes I need to replace 10, 20 or even more and it gets tedious.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when you want to replace:

- If during recording, then just define in User Defined Variables all the variables with their expected values , use Recording Template (Menu Templates > Recording) and start recording, JMeter will automagically replace for your
- If after recording, then you can open the XML file in an editor and do a search / replace by ${_afrLoop}